# how repeat one plot in multiples subplots matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Please I need repeat a climatological plot (fill_between(x,y1,y2) in multiples subplots, exist any tips to resolve that? Here is part of my code.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, sharex=True)
ax = axs[0,0]
ax.fill_between(month, y2,y3 , alpha=0.25, color='grey')
ax.errorbar(a1[0], a1[1], a1[2], marker='o')

ax = axs[0,1]
ax.fill_between(month, y2,y3 , alpha=0.25, color='grey')
ax.errorbar(a2[0], a2[1], a2[2], marker='o')

ax = axs[1,0]
ax.fill_between(month, y2,y3 , alpha=0.25, color='grey')
ax.errorbar(a3[0], a3[1], a3[2], marker='o')

ax = axs[1,1]
ax.fill_between(month, y2,y3 , alpha=0.25, color='grey')
ax.errorbar(a4[0], a4[1], a4[2], marker='o')
```

The data a1,a2,a3,....a24 because are 24 years come from

```
a1 = graf1.graf1('mon1992.dat')
a2 = graf1.graf1('mon1993.dat')
a3 = graf1.graf1('mon1994.dat')
a4 = graf1.graf1('mon1995.dat')
```

And graf1 is a module

```
import pandas as pd
def graf1(archivo):

archivo = '/Users/ccasiccia/Desktop/research/dataO3_180/' + archivo
data2 = pd.read_csv(archivo, delim_whitespace = True, header=None)

xd2 = data2.ix[:,0]
yd2 = data2.ix[:,1]
sd2 = data2.ix[:,2]

return xd2, yd2, sd2
```

Considering the data obtained with the graf1 function I need build figures with 4 subplots (2x2) and the question here is: how can add the clima plot (ax.fill_between(month, y2, y3, alpha=0.25, color='grey') in each subplots? but not how I did, repeating the instruction on each subplot. 
Follow the data to one year (ex. mon1996.dat)

```
1   290.1931    23.21468
2   280.32778   17.70719
3   274.70455   19.08037
4   292.43913   27.8067
5   292.49667   24.57176
6   301.64667   26.96397
7   323.13889   20.30883
8   319.76  22.01486
9   306.432 20.07016
10  310.54444   45.90831
11  341.484 27.99424
12  300.71935   12.98657
```

This is the climatological data for fill_between

```
1   322.418 20.25   20.287  342.668 302.168
2   315.1   21.534  21.578  336.634 293.566
3   293.268 23.694  23.738  316.962 269.574
4   292.928 26.499  26.55   319.427 266.429
5   301.565 31.153  31.21   332.718 270.412
6   304.135 35.883  35.953  340.018 268.252
7   317.792 36.85   36.916  354.642 280.942
8   321.36  35.798  35.863  357.158 285.562
9   324.558 33.472  33.535  358.03  291.086
10  336.043 45.679  45.762  381.722 290.364
11  338.736 33.518  33.58   372.254 305.218
12  327.578 27.093  27.144  354.671 300.485
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Can you add some of your data to have a minimal working example? What is the desired output and what is not working?

Comment: Thanks @MaximilianPeters I edited my question adding data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how the data is organized it may be quite easy to loop over the plots to fill them.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

month=np.linspace(1,8)
y2 = -0.15*(month-4)**2+2.3
y3 = 0.1*(month-3.7)**2
x = np.logspace(1,5,base=1.5, num=16).reshape(4,4).T
y = np.sinc(x-3)**2+1
yerr = np.sqrt(y)


fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, sharex=True)
for i, ax in enumerate(axs.flatten()):
    ax.fill_between(month, y2,y3 , alpha=0.25, color='gold')
    ax.errorbar(x[:,i], y[:,i],yerr[:,i], marker='o')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Dear @ImportanceOfBeignErnes how you mentioned the organization of data is very important, I edited my question including the way of read he data. I was looking for how read and plot (with subplots) using some tools of itinerancy or loops, but I was find nothing to help me, at least in my poor knowledge of python... thanks in advance